# Gmail rules doesn't include the proper destination address

Tags: gmail

I made in a gmail account a simple filter that replies with a standard message when the email object contains this string "Richiesta condivisione per":

[image]

The filter works because triger a reply only to messages with the ""Richiesta condivisione per" text in the object, byt it eeplies with a "strange" destination address...
Any suggestion? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add more details. Does the emails comes from only one sender? Does these emails have set a reply-to email address?

Comment: The email comes from Google Drive itself, the rules works if the message is sent from a personal address, otherwise not